# SQL UDF and query optimization

Tags: sql-server

If I use a SQL function in a select statement will it effect performance ? 
should I use sub query or UDF in Select statement in which case query will be most optimized ?

Comment: Also [Read here](http://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/user-defined-functions-and-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery will have better performance, but UDF can be reused much easier in other queries as well. You can use them to encapsulate specific calculations or logics at one place. If you need to change the logic you have to change only the UDF instead of changing all queries where you integrated that subquery. 
At the end you gain flexibility but loose a performance when including the function in queries with huge amount of records.

Comment: oops, ok alreay answered...

Answer (score 1):

Almost always will a subquery perform much better than UDF.

Comment: then what is the purpose of UDFs in SQL server ? Where they fit and used in most of the cases ?

Comment: @Afzal From top of the head you use then when you need to reuse the code or when you need to break a complex logic into modules. When database is small it can be more important to deploy it quickly, without worrying about performance.