# To Optimize a query which has UDF in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

```
SELECT *  FROM Items 
WHERE Items.StringColumn = 'XYZ_String' AND UserdefinedFunction(Id) = 1
```

For a query like above and table statistics like:

- 1-50 items which contains the string 'XYZ_String'.
- Total records in the Items table are in the order of 500K

Would it be beneficial to convert it into 2 queries, where the first query would do a string equality check and the second query would call the UDF on 50 something records?

Comment: SQL Server should be smart enough to short circuit and only run the UDF on rows that match the string comparison.  You can add an index on  StringColumn, UserdefinedFunction(Id) that should keep the query nice and quick.

Comment: Have you tried your solution and timed them to compare?

Answer (score 0):

1. No .. it would not. Getting an index on that column will help a lot though.
2. The user defined function that you use can be inlined (do you have inside it a query or something) ? If so the query will be better optimized if your function will be a tabled value function and your query will look like:

   ```
   SELECT *  
   FROM Items i cross apply UserdefinedFunction(Id) ii 
   WHERE Items.StringColumn = 'XYZ_String' 
   AND   ii.value = 1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Making to query is not good. Yes, alternate is You replace udf with sub-query or inner query

Please check this link.

[SQL UDF and query optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752107/sql-udf-and-query-optimization)

https://sqlserverfast.com/?s=user+defined+ugly